# how to receive numbers with input and move it in array and sort by ascending?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

how to receive numbers with input and move it in array and sort by ascending?
my code looks like but doesn't work:

```
<input id="number">
<p>Sorted:</p>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var nums = $("#number").val();
    var array = [nums];
    var x = array.sort().join(", ");
    $("p").append(x);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you write your numbers separated by space:

`var array = nums.split(' ');`

Answer (score 1):

- Split the string to char get array

  ```
   var array = num.toString().split('')
   or
   var array = num.split('') // if you are already dealing with string
  ```
- Sort and join again

  ```
   var sarray= array.sort().join('')
  ```
- [optional] return the parsed integer

  ```
  var snum = parseInt(sarray)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on how you are separating the numbers in your input. For example if you use `,` like `4,3,2,1`. Then you can do something like this:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var nums = $("#number").val().split(',').map(Number);//separating by comma
    var x = nums.sort().join(", ");
    $("p").append(x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Only even numbers:

```
var evenNumbers = array.filter(function(num) {
  return num % 2 == 0;
});
```

Comment: Note that if the asker has asked an additional question as an answer, they should post it as a new question instead. Answers should be for the original question only.

Comment: Yeah, it's unfortunate but the reviewers are likely to delete your answer anyway. :(